# sidebar with Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to do a sidebar with Reactjs but I am not getting it.

I want to know how to pass the props from App.js to Middle.js correctly.

I have the structure index.js > routes.js > App.js > Header.js, Middle.js > Sidebar.js, (DashboardPage.js, AccountPage.js - pages to be rendered dinamically)

Header.js -> Has a IndexLink at image
Sidebar.js -> Has a IndexLink and a Link to render AccountPage.js

The route is set for App.js, but the component is supposed to load inside the Middle.js component.

Here are my codes:

index.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import routes from './routes';

render(
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import DashboardPage from './components/middle/dashboard/DashboardPage';
import AccountPage from './components/middle/accounts/AccountPage';

export default (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={DashboardPage} />
        <Route path="accounts" component={AccountPage} />
    </Route>
);
```

App.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Header from './common/Header';
import Middle from './middle/Middle'
import '../../css/style.css';

class App extends React.Component{
    var { app } = this.props;
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Middle />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Header.js // IndexLink at img

'use strict';

```
import React from 'react';
import User from './User';
import {IndexLink, Link} from 'react-router';
import '../../../css/header.css';

class Header extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contactto-header">
                <div className="contactto-header-content">
                    <IndexLink to="/"><img className="contactto-header-content-logo" src="static/img/logo.png" alt="contactto logo" /></IndexLink>
                    <div className="contactto-header-content-alarm"></div>
                    <div className="contactto-header-content-user">
                        <User />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Middle.js

```
'use strict';

import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import '../../../css/middle.css';
import SideBar from './SideBar'

class Middle extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="contactto-middle">
                <div className="contactto-middle-content">
                    <SideBar />
                    {app.children} // should render here
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Middle;
```

Sidebar.js

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import {IndexLink, Link} from 'react-router';
import '../../../css/sidebar.css';

class SideBar extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sidebar-container">
                <ul className="sidebar-container-ul">
                    <li className="sidebar-container-ul-li">
                        <IndexLink className="sidebar-container-ul-li-a" to="/">Dashboard</IndexLink>
                    </li>
                    <li className="sidebar-container-ul-li">
                        <Link className="sidebar-container-ul-li-a" to="accounts">Contas</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SideBar;
```

What is wrong?

I am new with React, if another code is not done correctly please tell me :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your route components will be available under App through this.props.children. If you want to wrap them with  you can try like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Middle>
          {this.props.children}
        </Middle>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

An then in the Middle.js

```
class Middle extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="contactto-middle">
        <div className="contactto-middle-content">
          <SideBar />
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hii. I am having a similar scenario but the problem is: inside the SideBar component, I have used `<Link/>` from `react-router-dom` due to which, I get the error that "you cannot use Link outside Router". How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but it seems that you want to know how to pass a prop from App.js to Middle.js. Here's how:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    var { app } = this.props;
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Middle someProp={someValue} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now in Middle.js you can access someProp in `this.props.someProp`.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing the code: var { app } = this.props and I forget to erase. The question is, I want the DashBoardPage and AccountPage be rendered when I clink at the Link or IndexLink

Comment: It worked, it was just pass this.props.children to Middle. 
someProp={this.props.children}

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-side-bar. There are a complete example in [Example](https://github.com/mschez/react-side-bar/tree/develop/example) and looks fine.

`npm install --save react-side-bar`